# Do Until Loop in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

My loop doesn't seem to break. Not sure where am I going wrong. Cell C5 in tab "ABC" = 44.5%. Cell C4 in tab "ABC" = 32%. I have to list down percentages between 32% to 45% in column E. SO E9 = 32%, E10 = 33%, E22 = 45%. I have linked cell E9 to cell C4. My macro starts populating from cell E10. Cell C2 in tab "ABC" = 9

My macro keeps on running and doesn't stop at 45%.

```
Sheets("ABC").Select
i = Worksheets("ABC").Range("C2").Value + 1

Do Until Cells(i, 5).Value <= Round(Worksheets("ABC").Range("C5").Value, 0)
    Cells(i, 5).Value = Cells(i - 1, 5).Value + 0.01
    i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `>=` instead of `<=`?

Answer (score 1):

You are steadily increasing `Cells(i - 1, 5).Value` by `+ 0.01`.

So, `Cells(i - 1, 5).Value` gets bigger. Hence, I am assuming that the line:

```
Do Until Cells(i, 5).Value <= Round(Worksheets("ABC").Range("C5").Value, 0)
```

should really be:

```
Do Until Cells(i, 5).Value >= Round(Worksheets("ABC").Range("C5").Value, 0)
```

Furthermore, you are forgetting to set the starting point correctly. If I understand the post correctly then the starting point should be `Range("C4").Value`.

The rounding is not necessary as you are using `>=` and not `=`. So, it doesn't matter if there is an exact match. It merely needs to pass the threshold given in `Range("C5")`.

Finally, `Cells(i, 5).Value` will be always `=""` (empty) when the check is run because your loop will set `Cells(i, 5).Value` only **after** the check to a certain value. Hence, you need to verify the row before `Do Until Cells(i - 1, 5).Value...`

Bringing it all together I am guessing that you are looking for the following:

```
Option Explicit

Sub tmpSO()

Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ABC")
ws.Activate
i = ws.Range("C2").Value + 1

ws.Cells(i - 1, 5).Value2 = ws.Range("C4").Value2
Do Until ws.Cells(i - 1, 5).Value2 >= ws.Range("C5").Value2
    ws.Cells(i, 5).Value = ws.Cells(i - 1, 5).Value + 0.01
    i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Doing this skips the loop and ends the macro.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sheets("ABC").Select
i = Worksheets("ABC").Range("C2").Value + 1

Do Until Cells(i - 1, 5).Value >= Worksheets("ABC").Range("C5").Value
    Cells(i, 5).Value = Cells(i - 1, 5).Value + 0.01
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Ralph & Pspl,

Many thanks!! Your suggestions helped and worked for me. This is an excellent forum for new coders like me. Thanks again for your help.

```
For the benefit of the larger group, this is what I have finally used. 

Sheets("ABC").Select
i = Worksheets("ABC").Range("C2").Value + 1

Do Until Cells(i - 1, 5).Value >= Worksheets("ABC").Range("C5").Value
    Cells(i, 5).Value = Cells(i - 1, 5).Value + 0.01
    i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```